# Toggle Apple Mail "Classic Layout" with shortcut?

Tags: macos, mail.app, applescript

Can anyone figure out a way to switch Apple Mail (v5.2) to/from "Classic Layout" mode with a hotkey? Maybe via Applescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the applescript for it. Set this up as an app or something but this should get you started.

```
tell application "Mail" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "," using command down
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        click button 5 of tool bar 1 of window 1
        delay 0.1
        click checkbox "Use classic layout" of group 1 of group 1 of window "Viewing"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: That gives me an error, `System Events got an error: Can’t get window "Viewing" of process "Mail".` -- unless I had already previously selected the 'Viewing' pane of the Prefs window.

Comment: Sorry about that! Forgot to click that toolbar first. Edited my answer to include that.